# factor nearly identical classes in vb.net with constraints

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

I have 2 almost identical classes named Key1 and Key2 . 
This is the code for Key1 class:

```
 Private Class Key1
    Implements IComparable(Of Key1)
    Private _Valor As String

    Public ReadOnly Property Valor() As String
        Get
            Return Me._Valor.Trim().ToUpper()
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(valor As String)
        Me._Valor = valor.Trim().ToUpper()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Dim ret As Integer = Me.Valor.GetHashCode()
        Return ret
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        If IsNothing(obj) Then
            Return False
        ElseIf Not (TypeOf obj Is Key1) Then
            Return False
        ElseIf ReferenceEquals(obj, Me) Then
            Return True
        ElseIf obj.GetHashCode() <> Me.GetHashCode() Then
            Return False
        End If

        Dim tmp As Key1 = DirectCast(obj, Key1)

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp.Valor) Then
            Return False
        ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Valor) Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return Me.Valor = tmp.Valor
        End If

    End Function

    Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As Key1) As Integer Implements System.IComparable(Of Key1).CompareTo
        Return Me.Valor.CompareTo(other.Valor)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Me.Valor.ToString()
    End Function

    Public Function Clonar() As Key1
        Return New Key1(Me.Valor)
    End Function
End Class
```

Key2 code is almost the same only substitute Key1 for Key2:

1. copy Key1 code to notepad.exe
2. Edit->Replace
3. Find What: Key1
4. Replace With: Key2

What Can I do to not repeat these code 2 times with the following constraints:

- Key1 cannot be used in place of Key2
- Key2 cannot be used in place of Key1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like that:

```
Class KeyBase(Of T)
    Implements IComparable(Of KeyBase(Of T))

    Private _Valor As String

    Public ReadOnly Property Valor() As String
        Get
            Return Me._Valor.Trim().ToUpper()
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(valor As String)
        Me._Valor = valor.Trim().ToUpper()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Dim ret As Integer = Me.Valor.GetHashCode()
        Return ret
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        If IsNothing(obj) Then
            Return False
        ElseIf Not (TypeOf obj Is KeyBase(Of T)) Then
            Return False
        ElseIf ReferenceEquals(obj, Me) Then
            Return True
        ElseIf obj.GetHashCode() <> Me.GetHashCode() Then
            Return False
        End If

        Dim tmp As KeyBase(Of T) = DirectCast(obj, KeyBase(Of T))

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp.Valor) Then
            Return False
        ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Valor) Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return Me.Valor = tmp.Valor
        End If

    End Function

    Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As KeyBase(Of T)) As Integer Implements System.IComparable(Of KeyBase(Of T)).CompareTo
        Return Me.Valor.CompareTo(other.Valor)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Me.Valor.ToString()
    End Function

    Public Function Clonar() As KeyBase(Of T)
        Return New KeyBase(Of T)(Me.Valor)
    End Function
End Class

Class Key1
    Inherits KeyBase(Of Key1)

    Public Sub New(valor As String)
        MyBase.New(valor)
    End Sub
End Class

Class Key2
    Inherits KeyBase(Of Key2)

    Public Sub New(valor As String)
        MyBase.New(valor)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Iam going to try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can get the code down to this:

```
Public Class Key1
    Inherits Keys(Of Key1)
    Public Sub New(valor As String)
        MyBase.New(valor)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function Clonar() As Key1
        Return New Key1(Me.Valor)
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Key2
    Inherits Keys(Of Key2)
    Public Sub New(valor As String)
        MyBase.New(valor)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function Clonar() As Key2
        Return New Key2(Me.Valor)
    End Function
End Class
```

You need to create the following interface & base class to make this work:

```
Public Interface IKey
    ReadOnly Property Valor() As String
End Interface

Public MustInherit Class Keys(Of K As IKey)
    Implements IComparable(Of K)
    Implements IKey
    Private _Valor As String

    Public ReadOnly Property Valor() As String Implements IKey.Valor
        Get
            Return Me._Valor.Trim().ToUpper()
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(valor As String)
        Me._Valor = valor.Trim().ToUpper()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Dim ret As Integer = Me.Valor.GetHashCode()
        Return ret
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        If obj Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        ElseIf Not (TypeOf obj Is K) Then
            Return False
        ElseIf ReferenceEquals(obj, Me) Then
            Return True
        ElseIf obj.GetHashCode() <> Me.GetHashCode() Then
            Return False
        End If

        Dim tmp As K = DirectCast(obj, K)

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp.Valor) Then
            Return False
        ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Valor) Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return Me.Valor = tmp.Valor
        End If

    End Function

    Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As K) As Integer Implements System.IComparable(Of K).CompareTo
        Return Me.Valor.CompareTo(other.Valor)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Me.Valor.ToString()
    End Function

    Public MustOverride Function Clonar() As K

End Class
```

Comment: I going to try it. Thabnks